# Slash is replaced by another character in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating android studio 2.2.3, got this error, Any suggestions are most welcome, because unable to load projects in studio, all "\" in studio replaced by THAT character.

Check this image link:

[image: Project loading error occuring]

[PROJECT STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86ig.png)

Comment: can you please add snap of your project structure?

Comment: Kindly look again,question updated with Project structure @RajeshKushvaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happen because of you have set Japanese keyboard set it to default English and restart your studio. check this [official Microsoft answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other/change-yen-symbol-to-backslash/5bd48ad1-534e-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

You can change from `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language` enter in windows addressbar

Answer (score 1):

That happen because your path (floder name)contains other language(Chinese or other)in your system.when take path it gives  invalid character in SDK path(file name) android studio .so change that path name into english then path will come properly in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the japanese language on your system, but you don't need to change that. You can also go to your android studio and change the font.

Go to: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font

Create an copy of the default scheme, then change the primary font to one that supports the backslash.